# how to attach window.onload to specific page in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have script files that are global to all the pages and i want to attach window.onload to a specific view in asp.net mvc or element using jquery. Is that possible ??

Comment: Of course it's possible. https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: need proper syntax, please share it not the link

Comment: is that possible with onbeforeunload event too???

Comment: You, yourself, need to research first before asking questions here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.load()` to know if the content is loaded into the DOM. See the following example!

```js
$('img').load(function() {
  console.log('image loaded')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random" />
```